# Regex matching zero or none and Or

Tags: regex

How do I match a sequence of optional characters or a different character?

For example:

I started with matching the letters "KQkq"

these are in sequence but optional, so "K?Q?k?q?"

however the input is either one of those four letters or "-", so I tried "(K?Q?k?q?|-)"

this works for the letters, but won't match the "-"

If the letters weren't optional I'd use "(KQkq|-)", which works fine.

I've tried a number of different things, like putting the letters in a group "((K?Q?k?q?)|-)" but I can't quite find a way to express what I need.

*** Note: As I stated in the question: I'm matching the letters "KQkq" "in sequence but optional". Sequence means they come one after the other so "KQkq" is valid, "KkQq" is not valid, nor is "kqKQ" or "kkkk" or anything else that doesn't match the sequence KQkq. Optional means that a character may or may not exist. So "KQkq" is valid, as is "K" or "Kk" or "Qkq". Character classes, for those that don't know, will match any of the characters in the class with no sense of sequence. So [KQkq]{1,4} would indeed match "KQkq" and "Qkq" however it would also match "KKKK", "qkQK", "qqqq" none of which are valid.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. As it currently is written, it's really hard to understand what you're asking - especially when it comes to regular expressions. Best provide an example of what you have, and examples of matches you want, and matches you don't want. Also please tag the question with what language you're using, since there are many flavors of regular expressions.

Comment: You should read up on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: mkay, I added what sequence and optional mean for those who were unfamiliar with the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:K?Q?k?q?)|-)$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/2

Comment: Choosing this as the answer because it was submitted first and has a nice example even though M42's answer has a better explanation of the problem. (I would say thanks here but the button says I shouldn't say thanks, weird)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is working fine, in order to capture the dash you just need to anchor the regex:

```
^(K?Q?k?q?|-)$
```

Without anchor, the first part `K?Q?k?q?` matches anything, included empty string and `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `([KQkq]|-)` or even `([KQkq]|[-])`

Example: [Regex Example](http://regexr.com/3a4dm)

Comment: [KQkq] will match any of those letters, however it's doesn't address the issue of sequencing. So it would happily match "qkQK" which has the wrong sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets, like this: `/[KQkq]|-/`.  Anything inside square brackets is optional.  It literally means **match anything between the brackets**.

Comment: [KQkq] will match any of those letters, however it's doesn't address the issue of sequencing. So it would happily match "qkQK" which has the wrong sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need: `(K?Q?k?q?|-)`

Comment: I did try this and as I noted it works for the letters, however it does not capture the "-" and in fact it returns a match (with no capture) on bad input such as "asdfasdf".